# How do I sum up properties of a JSON object in coffescript?

Tags: json, coffeescript

I have an object that looks like this one:

```
object =
  title : 'an object'
  properties :
    attribute1 :
      random_number: 2
      attribute_values:
        a: 10
        b: 'irrelevant'
    attribute2 :
      random_number: 4
      attribute_values:
        a: 15
        b: 'irrelevant'
   some_random_stuff: 'random stuff'
```

I want to extract the sum of the 'a' values on attribute1 and attribute2.
What would be the best way to do this in Coffeescript?

(I have already found one way to do it but that just looks like Java-translated-to-coffee and I was hoping for a more elegant solution.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I came up with (edited to be more generic based on comment):

```
sum_attributes = (x) =>
  sum = 0
  for name, value of object.properties 
    sum += value.attribute_values[x]
  sum

alert sum_attributes('a') # 25
alert sum_attributes('b') # 0irrelevantirrelevant
```

So, that does what you want... but it probably doesn't do exactly what you want with strings. 
You might want to pass in the accumulator seed, like `sum_attributes 0, 'a'` and `sum_attributes '', 'b'`

Comment: Thank you! I guess I left out one piece of information, for which I am sorry. Assuming "b" was also a property that could be accumulated and I had a function that would accept a or b as a variable, would I be able to use the same approach?
I have tried to go along the lines of (given function input of x)
  for k,v of object.properties
    sum += value.attribue_values[x] 

which did not work. I am sorry that I forgot to leave that part out in my question, so I still upvoted the reply as it was spot on :)

Comment: @user957731: I edited my response to be more generic.  Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 3):

Brian's answer is good. But if you wanted to bring in a functional programming library like [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/), you could write a more succinct version:

```
sum = (arr) -> _.reduce arr, ((memo, num) -> memo + num), 0
sum _.pluck(object.properties, 'a')
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into that if I find myself doing these kind of things often.

Comment: +1 Yeah, I considered going there... but I thought I'd stick with CoffeeScript directly.

Answer (score 1):

```
total = (attr.attribute_values.a for key, attr of obj.properties).reduce (a,b) -> a+b
```

or

```
sum = (arr) -> arr.reduce((a, b) -> a+b)
total = sum (attr.attribute_values.a for k, attr of obj.properties)
```

Comment: I like that. It sent me googling on both list comprehension and folding. Seems I don't need to consider underscore.js then :) I can't get it to work when there is only one value that is to be included in the sum as reduce seems to be called on something that isn't an array but I have several cases where I need to do this kind of operation and I know that will not be the case.

Comment: oops. that's where underscore's pluck would help. you could use `(attr.attribute_values.a or 0 for key, attr of obj.properties)` too, despite being somewhat inneficient.